# Unable to change the mainClass for tomcat7-maven-plugin for goal 'exec-war-only'

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I am using embedded tomcat to run my web app. I am packaging tomcat in a jar file using the tomcat7-maven-plugin ([exec-war-mojo.html](https://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-trunk/tomcat7-maven-plugin/exec-war-mojo.html)). The plugin config that i am using is:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
             <goals>
                 <goal>exec-war-only</goal>
             </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <buildDirectory>${project.basedir}/</buildDirectory>
        <path>/</path>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}.jar</finalName>
        <enableNaming>true</enableNaming>
        <mainClass>com.main.Main</mainClass>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The problem is, when I build the .jar file, it does not contain the file pointed by  attribute as a result I am unable to run the .jar file as it looks for the Main.class file and I get the error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.main.Main
```

If I do not mention the `<mainClass>` attribute, the default value is picked up which is `org.apache.tomcat.maven.runner.Tomcat7RunnerCli` and everything runs fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the artifact which contains your main class as a dependency via 'extraDependencies', like this:

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <mainClass>com.main.Main</mainClass>
  <extraDependencies>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.main</groupId>
        <artifactId>yer-artifact</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
     </dependency>
  </extraDependencies>
</configuration>
```

Note that you will also have to explicitly add any transitive dependencies.